# Does gpg-agent have a GUI?

Tags: linux, encryption, gui, gpg, pgp

Is there a GUI of application `gpg-agent` ?
 How I can start it ? I need to change some settings there, but can't find it.

Comment: Seahorse is the GUI that works with the agent.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse & https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahorse_%28software%29?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1):

A list of settings and config files are mentioned here : 
[Options](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#Agent-Options) 
[Configurations](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Configuration.html#Agent-Configuration)

If you are specifically looking for a GUI then, use [seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse/Download)